# How to write a function called word_freq that accept a string and uses an accumlation pattern to return a dictionary?

Tags: python

> Write a function called word_freq that accepts a string as a formal parameter and uses an accumulation pattern to return a dictionary that contins the number of occurrences for each word in that string. Use the code below to test your function:
>
> ```
> s = 'it is what it is and only what it is'
> print(word_freq(s))
> ```
>
> If your function is written correctly, the dictionary below will be displayed.
>
> ```
> {'it': 3, 'is': 3, 'what': 2, 'and': 1, 'only': 1}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried till now? If you have written any code then please edit your post and include it.

Comment: Also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def word_freq(s):
    freq = {}
    s = s.split(' ')
    for i in s:
        if i in freq.keys():
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    return freq
```

Output for `print(word_freq('it is what it is and only what it is'))`:

```
{'it': 3, 'is': 3, 'what': 2, 'and': 1, 'only': 1}
```

What this does is it takes your string `s`. It defines a dictionary `freq` that will be used to count the number of times each word is in the string. Then it splits the string everywhere that there is a space, this splits the string into separate words and returns a list. After that it loops over that list, checks if the word is in the dictionary's keys (`it`, `what` and the other words will all be keys after the loop has finished). If so, it adds one to the amount of times it occurs. If not, it creates a key for the dictionary, calls it the word, and gives it a value of 1. Finally the function just returns the dictionary `freq`.

Comment: Doing someone's homework for them isn't helping them. A code-only answer like this may answer the question, but it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Ok, I edited it to include a explanation.